# Unable to access declared Global variables

Tags: python, tkinter, global-variables, nameerror

I have tried declaring a global variable that stores the returned database object. But it raise NameError exception.
Tried declaring the returned object as global but nothing useful happened.

```
import tkinter as tk
import mysql.connector
import tkinter.messagebox
# import connect

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Login To Database")
root.geometry("400x160")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

connectFrame = tk.Frame()
connectFrame.pack()

# Defining Functions


def unhidePassword():
    if (checked.get()):
        passwordEntry.configure(show="")
    elif (not checked.get()):
        passwordEntry.configure(show="*")


def createConnection():
    try:
        global db
        db = mysql.connector.connect(
            user=user.get(),
            host=host.get(),
            password=password.get(),
            database=database.get(),
            auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
        )
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(message="Connection Created Successfully")

    except mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError:
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror(
            message="Incorrect Data Entered")


# Creating Widgets

# introLabel = tk.Label(connectFrame, text="Connect To Database",
#                      padx = 15, pady = 10, bg = "#42caff")


userName_label = tk.Label(connectFrame, text="User Name: ")
user = tk.StringVar()
userName_entry = tk.Entry(connectFrame, bd=1, width=27, textvariable=user)

hostLabel = tk.Label(connectFrame, text="Host: ")
host = tk.StringVar()
hostEntry = tk.Entry(connectFrame, bd=1, width=27, textvariable=host)


passwordLabel = tk.Label(connectFrame, text="Password: ")
password = tk.StringVar()
passwordEntry = tk.Entry(connectFrame, bd=1, width=27, textvariable=password)
checked = tk.IntVar()  # For checking if check button is checked or not
showPass = tk.Checkbutton(connectFrame, variable=checked,
                          text="Show Password", command=unhidePassword)


dataBaseLabel = tk.Label(connectFrame, text="Database:  ")
database = tk.StringVar()
dataBaseEntry = tk.Entry(connectFrame, bd=1, width=27, textvariable=database)

connectBtn = tk.Button(
    connectFrame, text="Connect To Database", cursor="hand2", bd=0, bg="#0ffcdd", command=lambda: createConnection())
curosr = db.cursor()
curosr.execute("SELECT * FROM visitors")
print(curosr.fetchall())


userName_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
userName_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

hostLabel.grid(row=1, column=0)
hostEntry.grid(row=1, column=1)

passwordLabel.grid(row=2, column=0)
passwordEntry.grid(row=2, column=1)
passwordEntry.configure(show="*")
showPass.grid(row=2, column=2, ipadx=20)

dataBaseLabel.grid(row=4, column=0)
dataBaseEntry.grid(row=4, column=1)

connectBtn.grid(row=7, column=1, pady=15, ipady=5)


root.mainloop()
```

Tried Declaring returned object as global but still it shows not defined error. However my Editor is able to access the methods and attributes. Can anyone explain What is this?

Comment: Please add the full error code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Your posting is missing the full error message, and you've posted far more code than required to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

to run your script I’ve made some changes.

- import MySQLdb as mdb
- import sys

so your script look as

```
 import tkinter as tk
import MySQLdb as mdb
import tkinter.messagebox
import sys

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Login To Database")
root.geometry("400x160")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)


connectFrame = tk.Frame()
connectFrame.pack()

# Defining Functions


def unhidePassword():
    if (checked.get()):
        passwordEntry.configure(show="")
    elif (not checked.get()):
        passwordEntry.configure(show="*")


def createConnection():
    try:
        global db
        db = mdb.connect(
            user=user.get(),
            host=host.get(),
            password=password.get(),
            database=database.get(),
            auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
        )
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(message="Connection Created Successfully")

    except :
        msg = (sys.exc_info()[1],
                       sys.exc_info()[0],
                       sys.modules[__name__])
        print(msg)
        #tkinter.messagebox.showerror(msg)


# Creating Widgets

# introLabel = tk.Label(connectFrame, text="Connect To Database",
#                      padx = 15, pady = 10, bg = "#42caff")


userName_label = tk.Label(connectFrame, text="User Name: ")
user = tk.StringVar()
userName_entry = tk.Entry(connectFrame, bd=1, width=27, textvariable=user)

hostLabel = tk.Label(connectFrame, text="Host: ")
host = tk.StringVar()
hostEntry = tk.Entry(connectFrame, bd=1, width=27, textvariable=host)


passwordLabel = tk.Label(connectFrame, text="Password: ")
password = tk.StringVar()
passwordEntry = tk.Entry(connectFrame, bd=1, width=27, textvariable=password)
checked = tk.IntVar()  # For checking if check button is checked or not
showPass = tk.Checkbutton(connectFrame, variable=checked,
                          text="Show Password", command=unhidePassword)


dataBaseLabel = tk.Label(connectFrame, text="Database:  ")
database = tk.StringVar()
dataBaseEntry = tk.Entry(connectFrame, bd=1, width=27, textvariable=database)

connectBtn = tk.Button(connectFrame, text="Connect To Database", cursor="hand2", bd=0, bg="#0ffcdd", command=lambda: createConnection())




userName_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
userName_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

hostLabel.grid(row=1, column=0)
hostEntry.grid(row=1, column=1)

passwordLabel.grid(row=2, column=0)
passwordEntry.grid(row=2, column=1)
passwordEntry.configure(show="*")
showPass.grid(row=2, column=2, ipadx=20)

dataBaseLabel.grid(row=4, column=0)
dataBaseEntry.grid(row=4, column=1)

connectBtn.grid(row=7, column=1, pady=15, ipady=5)


root.mainloop()
```

so when you try to connect you would see this error reported by sys

```
(TypeError("'auth_plugin' is an invalid keyword argument for connect()"), <class 'TypeError'>, <module '__main__' (built-in)>)
```

if you delete this row

```
 auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
```

the script should work.

However, this is not the right way to do what you want.